# Secure passwords in Spring Boot apps for Production using Jasypt?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, security, passwords

As far as I see, there are some approaches for keeping passwords in Spring Boot apps e.g. Jasypt. I read some documentation for Jasypt, but could not understand some points. Could you clarify me on these points?

1- I want to secure passwords especially in `application.properties.yml`, `docker-compose.yml` files. I don't want to use Cloud services and for this situation, is Jasypt the best option for me? Or would you suggest a more proper approach for this purpose?

2- I am wondering how to use the app after I secure using Jasypt in PRODUCTION environment on Docker container. For example, the customer create app and database containers on Docker using the provided jar file and necessary commands. In that case, should I provide them the same commands modified for Jasypt with the necessary key used in Jasypt command? I am confused with this scenario.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea about the usage scenario of Jasypt for Production (the steps that customer should follow)?

Comment: JaSypt appears to be insecure crud you should definitely not be using. Its main page is __not__ https, the documentation is badly written, it touts 'sane defaults' everywhere without explaining what they are, and when you then delve into code to see them, the defaults are very much not sane. It appears to be very easy to write well-below state-of-the-art setups with this library unless you really know what you are doing. Given that this library _actively steers_ into the notion that you don't really need to figure it all out, that is very bad.

Comment: More generally you misunderstand what it is for. "secure passwords in property files" is __not possible__. What 'secure passwords' in JaSypt terms is doing, is: You are writing, say, stackoverflow.com, there are useraccounts, they have passwords, how do you store these in the DB. That is a very different concept.

Comment: If you don't want API keys and the like to be in your docker images, there are ways you can tell docker to 'send' properties from your local machine into the virtual host. That's generally how you do it. Various tutorials exist, I'm not familiar enough with docker to write an answer for you.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thanks for help, actually I am looking for a proper way to hide password on the app props and compos files. I also could not find a better option :(